# get an enum from ExecuteMethodCall()

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, enums

I have a legacy stored procedure (which I can't change).  It returns an int, and declaring the Linq2Sql method to return an int (like so) works fine:

```
public int spExample_upd(
    [Parameter(Name = "Id1", DbType = "int")] int id1,
    [Parameter(Name = "Id2", DbType = "int")] int id2)
{
    IExecuteResult result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), id1, id2);
    return (int)result.ReturnValue;
}
```

The sproc only returns a limited set of results, only 0, 1, and -1.  Instead of returning an int (in my C# code), I'd like spExample_upd() to return an enum:

```
public enum DbReturn
{
    Success = 0,
    Failure = 1,
    NoCountOn = -1
}
```

When I declare spExample_upd() to return a DbReturn:

```
public DbReturn spExample_upd(
    [Parameter(Name = "Id1", DbType = "int")] int id1,
    [Parameter(Name = "Id2", DbType = "int")] int id2)
{
    IExecuteResult result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), id1, id2);
    return (DbReturn)result.ReturnValue;
}
```

...I'm getting a run-time error of "DbReturn is not a valid return type for a mapped stored procedure method."  This happens when ExecuteMethodCall() is called, so I'm not even able to get back a result and then try casting it.

I tried forcing/coercing the return type for the method info by changing spExample_upd() to be:

```
[return: Parameter(DbType = "Int")]
[ResultType(typeof(int))]
public DbReturn spExample_upd(
    [Parameter(Name = "Id1", DbType = "int")] int id1,
    [Parameter(Name = "Id2", DbType = "int")] int id2)
{
    IExecuteResult result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), id1, id2);
    return (DbReturn)result.ReturnValue;
}
```

...but this didn't have any result (I still got the run-time error).

is it possible to call ExecuteMethodCall, get the int returned from the sproc, cast it to a DbReturn, and then have spExample_upd() return the DbReturn?

Comment: Its not a good practice to change LINQ2SQL Stored procedures return type in your code. Because everytime you will update your Data Model then your code will get lost.
So its Better to use enum in your C# code itself, where you want to use the result.

Comment: If no one provides you with an acceptable answer, you might also be able to improve the API experience by using extension methods to convert the integer result into something easier to look at e.g. result.Succeeded() or result.ToDbResult() != DbResult.Failed etc. This should allow you to improve the legacy API without touching the code around it too much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by the conflict between the MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod() call which is creating a MethodInfo instance that represents the signature of the current method (including the return type) and the ExecuteMethodCall() call which is validating that the return value of that signature is appropriate. The moment you change the return type of the method, the validation inside ExecuteMethodCall() detects that the signature isn't appropriate and produces the error you see.

You can work-around the problem by having a publicly exposed API using the enumeration and an internal API that uses an integer, but this is pretty much doing what Rahul suggested in his comment. Ideally you have a layer somewhere that hides the database specific bits and pieces from the client API, and the DataContext probably isn't the best place for that despite the work-around below working.

```
public DbReturn spExample_upd(int id1)
{
    return (DbReturn)spExample_upd_internal(id1);
}

[Function(Name = "spExample_upd")]
private int spExample_upd_internal([Parameter(Name = "Id1", DbType = "int")] int id1)
{
    var result = ExecuteMethodCall(this, (MethodInfo)MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod(), id1);
    return (int)result.ReturnValue;
}
```

Comment: That occurred to me, but the only issue though is that the change I need to make isn't code for just one sproc, there are a dozen.  Also, most of the sprocs have 2-6 parameters passed, but 2 of them have a ridiculous number of parameters passed (one has 40 parameters, the other 24).  This is a legacy codebase, and all changes get fairly scrutinized, so creating public/private methods is going to be harder to argue and justify and get through, but to me it seems like the best solution.  I was hoping there was a way to coerce ExecuteMethodCall() to determine the return parameter a different type

Comment: @Jeff, I did decompile the ExecuteMethodCall to see if there was an attribute used internally but it seemed to use the MethodInfo directly. I then briefly pondered synthesizing a MethodInfo from say a Func<T> but based on other StackOverflow posts this seemed non trivial too. Sorry it wasn't quite what you were looking for (and that you have to maintain methods with 40 parameters) :)